# Ignore Pods on Xcode refactoring?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, swift, cocoapods

Is it possible to ignore Pods when doing Xcode refactoring? When I do even very simple refactoring, for example rename variable in my project, Xcode starts to scan whole workspace. How can I prevent this behaviour and limit scope to my project?

Answer (score 1):

Because Xcode needs to know about everything that could possibly be affected, it's going to scan everything regardless, but you can still limit the scope of what's actually changed in the preview. When you preview your refactoring changes, make sure the Project View tab is selected in the lefthand pane, then uncheck anything you don't want included.

Comment: Thank you for response. For me this behaviour seems strange, I have to exclude changes in Pods in 1% cases when my names clash. But time difference between scanning my projects and whole workspace with 20+ pods is huge

Comment: How can it refactor symbols safely without knowing all linked symbols? There's no real solution to that problem. Granted it's slow as hell but that would seem to be the real issue.

Comment: Well, yeah, ideally. :-) But Xcode is notoriously behind other IDEs in this regard.